# Form Not Working After Converting to Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've got the following form that's fully working, but is just basic and ugly:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I try to convert it to a bootstrap form, like below, the Submit button does not actually submit changes. Any idea why this isn't working? When I hit Submit the values display as None, and when I go back to my selection screen the edits are not updated (they are also not updated in the backend database). Any idea what's wrong?

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.stakeholder_group.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.stakeholder_group.id_for_label }}">Stakeholder Group</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Add a Stakeholder Group"  value="{{ form.stakeholder_group.value }}">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">What group(s) is this invdividual associated with?</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.employee.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.employee.id_for_label }}">Employee Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Log the employee" value="{{ form.employee.value }}">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Who does this individual report to?</small>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Updated:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        <label for="{{ form.stakeholder_group.id_for_label }}"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Add a Stakeholder Group"  value="{{ field.value }}"> {{ field }}
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">What group(s) is this invdividual associated with?</small>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your form fields are missing. for e.g. if one if the fields is stakeholder_name then you need to add `{{form.stakeholder_name}}`

Comment: Is that not what value = {{form.stakeholder_name.value}} is doing? Where would I put {{form.stakeholder_name}} to make sure it's still within that formatted text box?

Comment: original post updated with the current results.... I want to have the functionality of the bottom text box (e.g. it's working when I hit submit) but then the aesthetics of the top

Comment: defne a form and then add classes to the field in the init method

Comment: Do you have any walkthroughs/references on how to best do that? I've tried this before and have run into errors